# Control key stuck on RDP from OS X to Windows

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-desktop

I'm using OS X 10.9.1 to connect to a Windows 2003 session via RDP. I'm trying to understand why the RDP session occasionally acts as if a man's finger is on the control key. If I were to type "HELLO" in a Windows 2003 console window, for example, I'd see ^H^E^L^L^O. What's worse is if I type "C", RDP sends over a Control-C which acts as a break/termination signal for the console app!

The only way to fix the problem is to disconnect the RDP session (Cmd-Q) and reestablish it.

It's happening several times per day, and I am growing weary of the thing. Any ideas what might be happening here?

Comment: I also see this with Linux Remmina client.

Answer (score 3):

This also happens to me, usually with the `Alt` key when running RemoteApp over a laggy connection (this happens when I press `Alt-Tab`, release the keys, very fast, the window changes and then when I return to the RemoteApp, the key is still pressed).

My solution is to press the "stuck" key twice. This usually works for me, without the need to disconnect.

The alternative is to give it a bit of time when switching between the remote session and a local app, as this should send all the information down the wire, including the KeyUp event.

Comment: interesting. I'll give it a try and let you know how it works.